# How to open .xlsx files using Intents in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, xamarin, kingsoft

I am using the following Intent to open .xlsx file using an Intent Chooser. I have Kingsoft Offie and Polaris office at my disposal to open these files.

```
var calcIntent = new Intent ();             
calcIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionView);
Android.Net.Uri fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile (new File (OSUtils.GetCalcFilePath (id)));
calcIntent.SetData (fileUri);
var mimeType = OSUtils.GetMimeType (fileUri.ToString ());
calcIntent.SetType (mimeType);                  
try {
     StartActivity (Intent.CreateChooser (calcIntent, "Open Via"));
 } catch (ActivityNotFoundException) {
    Toast.MakeText (this, "You do not have Kingsoft Office Installed!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Where OSUtils.GetCalcFilePath is defined as

```
public static string GetCalcFilePath (int currentId) {
    var calcDirPath = OSUtils.GetCalcDirForEstimate (currentId);
    var calcSheetName = String.Format ("builder_calc_{0}.xlsx", currentId);
    var calcSheet = new Java.IO.File (calcDirPath, calcSheetName);
    if (!calcSheet.Exists ()) {
        calcSheet.CreateNewFile ();
    }
    return calcSheet.Path;
}
```

and OSUtils.GetMimeType is defined as

```
public static string GetMimeType (string fileUri) {
    String mimeType = null;
    var extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl (fileUri);
    if (extension != null) {
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension (extension);
    }
    if (mimeType != null)
  return mimeType;
    else
        return "*/*";
}
```

Now when I run it, I get a dialog(chooser) giving me two options, "Kingsoft Office" and "Polaris Office". Choosing Polaris Office gives me a toast saying "Not a supported document type" and on the other hand choosing Kingsoft Office just opens up the Kingsoft App and does nothing. The document is not opened in Kingsoft Office.
Whereas, if I go to my file manager and tap on the .xlsx file, it opens up perfectly in both the office apps. I checked my code and all the mimetypes and paths are correct and are pointing to the desired file. Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**

It seems using SetData and SetType individually wont work here. They are mutually exclusive i.e calling one clears the other. "SetDataAndType" is the way to go here. :)

Comment: Issue with for file path , which you are not passing properly

Comment: I am passing it properly. I have found my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using SetData and SetType individually wont work here. They are mutually exclusive i.e calling one clears the other.
"SetDataAndType" is the way to go here. :)